# http restAPI calls on a https webiste

Tags: node.js, rest, http, ssl, https

I have a https webiste. There is a rest call with POST method on a http target. Ideally http access over https should give errors but it gives response without any error. The http rest call responds with an excel file which gets downloaded.

Do restAPI calls bypass SAME ORIGIN POlICY ( since in my case there is difference of protocol ) ?

****Edited****
I converted a subdomain of my website to  https ( for testing purpose) . So earlier there was a dropdown which on select would trigger a rest call to another URL ( same domain but different subdomain ( both http) ). This rest call would result in an excel file download.

Now one subdomain  is https. Still that dropdown works and rest call is success and results in downloads ( now protocols of both subdomains are different). Shouldn't browser block rest call from executing ?

rest call from one subdomain ( https) to another subdomain ( http and using POST method)

Comment: where are you making the http request from and where does it connect to?

Comment: @mihai I have edited to make it clear